# Evaluate string as a conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, evaluation

I am working on a c++ web-based IDE for beginners where one of it's core function is to let the user know the evaluation result (**true** or **false**) of the conditional statement they have on my contenteditable div.

Say i am already able to fetch the "fragment" (what i call it based on my architecture) that i wanted to evaluate and i already know the values of the variables...

Can you please suggest a way on how would i evaluate the text on the fragment as a conditional statement that will return either true or false...

Example

when `var b = 5;`

```
$('.frag').eq(1).text() //"if( (b>1) || (b==10) )"
```

after evaluation(what im asking for help) should return `true`

```
 $('.frag').eq(2).text() //"(b>1)"
```

should return `true`

```
 **$('.frag').eq(3).text() //"(b==10)"
```

should return `false`

**UPDATE**

The problem i am seeing with eval is that if i have a var1 in the contenteditable div and i have a var1 in my code. I should put a header on the variables from the contenteditable then right? like sc_var1 to prevent messing up with var1 from my source code?

Comment: Sounds like one of the few cases where `eval` could help...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a String / text input field as a condition in a JavaScript if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322388/using-a-string-text-input-field-as-a-condition-in-a-javascript-if-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eval like this:

```
var expression = $('.frag').eq(1).text();
var result = eval(expression);
```

However I generally do not recommend using eval because there is always a much better workaround.

if I get the bigger picture of your needs I would be able to provide a better solution.