# Generate an if from user input

Tags: javascript

I have a page where user can select different IF sentences, by selection different(noumerous) select/options.

And I want to pass that user-generated arguments to local js function, like that

```
var userOptions = [
  'p>0', 'r>2', 'b==0' //String or other type sentences, generated by user on page. Number of those sentences is not defined.
];

function valdate (p, r, b) {
if (userOptions) { //Here we should check that all sentences, required by user is true
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Cant' figure out how do I pass userOptions to IF sentence. Pls help.

**Some operand cand be functions, like 'getVal(b)>0'**

Comment: This is similar to what you're asking. I don't recommend `eval` either. It can be dangerous with user generated input. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842283/evaluate-string-as-a-conditional-statement

Answer (score 0):

Think switch operator will help you:

```
var cond;
switch(opt){
    case 'p>0': cond = p>0; break;
    case 'r>2': cond = r>2; break;
    case 'b==0': cond = b==0; break;
}
if (cond) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the select option **'p>0'**

1/ Retrieve which operator is involved *(>)*

2/ Split the string in two part *(p and 0)*

3/ Use Regexp to see what contains each part. Function, number ...

4/ If the part is a function, call it. If the part is a number, use **parseInt()**

5/ Do your If